# Why is my parlour palm which is young and in the house getting brown spots

Tags: watering

I don't have a garden I am just trying to find out what is causing brow spots on my parlour palm tree that is quite young is it the soil.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a parlor palm, and had trouble with browning tips and spots on my leaves. Not sure if yours are manifesting similarly. A picture might help. But I read that these plants are sensitive to micronutrients in tap water, and that it's best to give a slow release plant fertilizer, and water with distilled water. So I tried it, and it's doing great. No expert here, it's just what I read and it seems to have worked. I cut back all the damaged leaves and new shoots came up soon after.